# Design of server component in Scala

Tags: scala, client-server, actor, future

Suppose I need to a `Scala` component to process incoming requests concurrently and return the processing results. Suppose also that the request processing consists of a few steps. Some of the steps are resource and time consuming, some of them are either I/O or CPU-bound, etc.

Assuming that requests come from *inside* the JVM I would design the component as follows:

- actor "Facade" is the entry point: it receives requests and sends the results to the clients.
- actor "Dispatcher" execute processing steps asynchronously with `Futures`, which wrap the steps
- steps send their results back to the "Dispatcher" actor. It's implemented with `Future` callbacks.
- When the request processing finish "Dispatcher" sends the results to "Facade".

Does it make sense? Are there any good examples of such a component in Scala?

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense given the details you showed.

A good framework for such case would be [Akka](http://akka.io). See the examples available in the source code, and the many open sourced projects in GitHub.